# Performing javadoc comments

Tags: java, javadoc

I'm reading a lot of articles about javadoc, but still can't menage when the "boilerplate" begins. In this example:

```
/**
 * Returns a list of tasks for specific user
 * @param userId
 * @return Selected list of tasks
 */
List<Task> getTasksForUser(Integer userId);

/**
 * Returns a list of tasks in chosen month and year
 * @param month
 * @param year
 * @return selected list of tasks
 */
List<Task> getTasks(Integer month, Integer year);
```

Can I perform them somehow to be less boilerplate or I should just remove them?

Why in 75% of articles called "best practices for Javadoc we have repetitions?
For example:

```
/**
 * Returns a list of tasks using params month, year
 * @param month
 * @param year
 * @return a list of tasks
 */
List<Task> getTasks(Integer month, Integer year);
```

Isn't it writing 2 times same thing?

Comment: Instead of relying on Javadoc, use appropriate types and argument names; for example, instead of `int month` and `int year` use the enums `java.time.Month` and `java.time.Year`. That also prevents callers accidentally transposing the two arguments. (Also, I've noticed you're using `Integer` instead of `int`. Why? Use of surprising argument types should always be explained in the Javadoc. For example, is it because they may be null?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To a certain degree, this is about "style". Nonetheless, let's have a look:

```
/**
 * Returns a list of tasks for specific user
 * @param userId
 * @return Selected list of tasks
 */
List<Task> getTasksForUser(Integer userId);
```

Some people argue that there is a certain merit in having

- a human readable description that tells you what a method does
- additional information using the @param / @return tags

You could for example rewrite this like:

```
/**
 * Returns a list of tasks for specific user.
 * @param userId denotes the user by his numeric id
 * @return Selected list of tasks (maybe empty, never null)
 */
List<Task> getTasksForUser(Integer userId);
```

So - in your example there is room to use the additional tags to provide actually *different* information: each line in my version serves a certain purpose, whereas your example just *repeats* the same information, albeit using slightly different wording.

But as said, in the end, this is a matter of style, and the key point is: you should pick that "style" that you (and your peers) find to be the most helpful for your context.

And please note: instead of repeating "obvious" things over and over again, a more helpful comment could rather look like this:

```
/**
 * @return The tasks selected for the given user (maybe empty, never null)
 * @throws UnknownUserException when <code>userId></code> is not known
 */
List<Task> getTasksForUser(Integer userId);
```

Which is basically "my" preferred style - to go with a single @return line. But instead mention crucial aspects such as - this method is throwing that runtime exception if ...

One final note there: having "empty" @param lines (that only give the parameter name) is a clear no-go. These lines tell you **nothing** - but you still have to spend time reading and **ignoring** them. Such things are **waste**. Avoid that.

Comment: great answer. You really shared with me a lot of knowledge. Really appreciate it. :)

Comment: I have a question about your final note. Empty param - no-go. So in the second example when I have param month, and param year should I just delete those lines? Because param month is just month, hard to say something else about a variable like this.

Comment: @degath  My personal take here: A) you could say some more - like in "what is the base of your month" --- is it going from 0 to 11, or 1 to 12 B) same for year - is that "really" the year, or say the number of years since 1900?! But then: I would rather "put" that information into the **names** of your parameters, as in "int zeroBasedMonth" or something like this. If a name is such that you have to look into code/comments to understand its meaning, then that name should be improved.

Comment: You should also be aware that many Java development tools (IDE) read the JavaDoc and display it when you instantiate a class or call a method and stuff like that. So it can be helpful if you provide additional parameter info so the IDE can display it when you actually are at the place the argument is passed to the method.